# React-native-camera error when compiling android

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-camera

I tried to upgrade my react native project to the newest version (0.59.2). Unfortunately, now when trying to run react-native run-android im getting this error:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve project :react-native-camera.
 Required by:
     project :app
  > Cannot choose between the following variants of project :react-native-camera:
      - generalDebugRuntimeElements
      - mlkitDebugRuntimeElements
    All of them match the consumer attributes:
      - Variant 'generalDebugRuntimeElements':
          - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
          - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'generalDebug' but wasn't required.
          - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
          - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
          - Found react-native-camera 'general' but wasn't required.
      - Variant 'mlkitDebugRuntimeElements':
          - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
          - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'mlkitDebug' but wasn't required.
          - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
          - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
          - Found react-native-camera 'mlkit' but wasn't required.
```

I have already tried to create a new project however this results in the same error.
Reinstalling the node modules didn't help either.
On iOS it works fine.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Insert the following lines in `android/app/build.gradle`

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general' <-- insert this line
  }
}
```

Comment: Mark this as the answer, it's super helpful :)

Comment: I have added this, the app builds when I run `run-android` and also when I build from Android Studio. But I get `Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-face-model:12.0.1.` error when I use `./gradlew assembleRelease`

Comment: Even after adding it , I m still getting the same Error .

Comment: I wasn't able to find 

```

Insert the following lines in android/app/build.gradle

> android {
 
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general' <-- insert this line
  }
}

Should I create this ?

This is how my build.gradle looks
https://codeshare.io/eVVJ9l

Comment: Thank You bro.... You saved my lots of time...

Answer (score 6):

Please insert the following line in `android/app/build.gradle` inside `defaultConfig` block either

```
missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
```

or

```
missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'mlkit'
```

Add jitpack to `android/build.gradle`

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}
```

[Complete guide](https://github.com/react-native-camera/react-native-camera/blob/master/docs/migrationV2.md#android)

[Could not resolve project :react-native-camera. on Android](https://github.com/react-native-camera/react-native-camera/issues/2150#issuecomment-476011915)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps.

### Step 1:

Change the class path in android/build.gradle in dependencies tag to this:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
```

### Step:2:

Change the gradle version in android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to this:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```

### Step 3:

In the android/app/build.gradle add this at the top:

```
  defaultConfig {
    missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general' 
  }
}
```

### Step 4:

Also add these two lines:

```
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } 
maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
```

Camera works now.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple to resolve by adding **missingDimensionStrategy** attribute in **defaultConfig** tag in `android/app/build.gradle`.

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
  }
}
```

If you are still having the same issue then you have to do the following steps.

Ensure that your **gradle build tool version is greater than 3.3.0**. You can use 3.4.1 for this purpose. Change the gradle build tool version from `android/build.gradle` file **buildscript** dependencies attributes.

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1")
    }
}
```

Also have to change the **gradle wrapper to 4.4 or later**. You can change the gradle version in `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` to this

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

Finally add the following lines in repositories tag of `android/build.gradle`

```
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } 
maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
```